# SilverSearcher - Why can I use `--ignore=PATTERN` when documentation says `--ignore PATTERN` without a equal sign?

Tags: ag

I had to ignore multiple directories, so I tried

```
ag --hidden --ignore '.git' --ignore 'plugged' -g ""
```

But this process of narrating `--ignore` each time I tried to ignore a directory felt needless. So, I tried with bash curly brace completion like in the following:

```
ag --hidden --ignore {.git,plugged} -g ""
```

But it didn't work, and rightfully so. Because the stuff inside the curly braces, after completion would look like

```
ag --hidden --ignore .git plugged -g ""
```

After browsing a little I tried:

```
ag --hidden --ignore={.git,plugged} -g ""
```

And it worked. But why using `--ignore=PATTERN` yield same result as `--ignore PATTERN` when the documentation (man ag) clearly states the way to be `--ignore PATTERN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `ag`'s command line parsing vs. its documentation. See:

1. https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/778
2. https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/pull/707

In this specific case, since `ag` properly reads the ignore pattern with and without the equal sign, it seems more like an undocumented feature than a short coming.